# Simple way to remove multi-line string using sed

Tags: text, sed, replace

Using sed, is there a way to remove multiple lines from a text file based on some starting and ending expressions?

I have known markers in the file and want to remove everything between (markers inclusive). I have seen some really complicated solutions and I would like to do this without resorting to micro commands.

My file looks something like this:

```
cat /tmp/foobar.txt
this is line 1

this is line 3

tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=\
annotations-api.jar,\
ant-junit*.jar,\
ant-launcher.jar,\
ant.jar,\
asm-*.jar,\
aspectj*.jar,\
bootstrap.jar,\
catalina-ant.jar,\
catalina-ha.jar,\
catalina-ssi.jar,\
catalina-storeconfig.jar

the end leave me
and me
```

I want to remove everything starting at `tomcat.util` all the away to the last `.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr;

I think this is the simplest way, ad no need for the assembly like micro commands

```
sed '/^tomcat\.util.*$/,/^.*[^\]$/d' /tmp/foobar.txt
```

which produces

```
this is line 1

this is line 3


the end leave me
and me
```

if you wanted to remove the lines in the file rather than spit out the output to stdout then use the `inline` flag, so

```
sed -i '/^tomcat\.util.*$/,/^.*[^\]$/d' /tmp/foobar.txt
```

So... how does this work?

`sed` commands, like `vi` commands operate on an `address`. Normally we don't specify an address and that simply applies the command to all lines of the file, eg when replacing `the` for `that` in a file we'd normally  do

```
sed -i 's/the/that/g' /tmp/foobar.txt
```

ie applying the substitute or `s` command to all lines in the file.

In this case you want to ***delete*** some lines so we can use the delete or `d` command. But we need to tell it where to delete. So we need to give it an address.

The format of a `sed` command is

```
[addr][!]command[options]
```

(see [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-script-overview.html#sed-script-overview) )

If no address is specified then the command is applied to all lines, if the `!` is specified then it is applied to all lines that don't match the pattern. So far so good.

The trick here is that `addr` can be a single address or a range of addresses. The address can be a line number or a regex pattern. You use a `,`  between two addresses to to specify a range.

so to delete line 5 to 8 inclusive you could do

```
sed -i '5,8d' /tmp/foobar.txt
```

in this case rather than knowing the line number we know some "markers" and we can use Regex instead, so the first marker, a line starting with `tomcat.util` is found by the regex

```
/^tomcat\.util.*$/
```

The second marker is a bit more tricky but if we look we can see that the final line to remove is the first one that does not end with a `\`, so we can match a line that consists of "anything but does not end with `\`"

```
/^.*[^\]$/
```

While the second marker could match a whole bunch of lines if we make a range out of these two regexes, the range means that the second "address" is the first line after the first address that matches the regex.

Putting that all together, we want to delete (`d`) all lines in the range from the address that is found by the regex matching a line starting with `tomcat.util` and ending with a line that does not end in `\` ie

```
sed '/^tomcat\.util.*$/,/^.*[^\]$/d' /tmp/foobar.txt
```

hope that helps ;-)

Cheers

Karl

Comment: no worries. cheers.

Comment: When the `tomcat.util` line doesn't end with a `\`, the next line(s) are removed too.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/tomcat\.util/{:a;n;/\.jar/ba};p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing using the `-n` option.

Match on a line containing `tomcat.util`.

Continue fetching lines until such a line does not match one containing `.jar`.

Print all other lines.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -E '/tomcat\.util/{:a;$!N;/\.jar(,\\)?$/s/\n//;ta;D}' file
```

Gather up lines beginning `tomcat.util` and ending either `.jar,\` or `.jar`, removing newlines until the end-of-file or a mis-match and then delete the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is generally more useful than sed for anything spanning lines. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '!/\.jar/{f=0} /tomcat\.util/{f=1} !f' file
this is line 1

this is line 3


the end leave me
and me
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too. I have to say I didn't even think of `awk` and you are right the solution is nice and clean.